# JavaScript: Allow Users To Change The Background Image

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, background

I'm trying code "JavaScript: Allow Users To Change The Background Image" like 
[this video on youtube](http://youtu.be/4_LyXs6RxhM?list=UUCmSCACs1A-X48MoUiRXleQ)
 but I still cannot make it work.

This code :
**index.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Change Back Ground </title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="core/changebg.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<?php
  session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['image'])) {
 echo'<script type="text/JavaScript">
 changeImage('.$_SESSION['image'].')</script>';
}  
?>
    <div id="choosebg" style="background-color:#f2f2f2; width:200px; padding:10px;text-align:center;" >
       <a href="#" onclick="changeImage(1);"><img src="images/1.jpg" width="50" hieght="50" /></a>
       <a href="#" onclick="changeImage(2);"><img src="images/2.jpg" width="50" hieght="50" /></a>
       <a href="#" onclick="changeImage(3);"><img src="images/3.jpg" width="50" hieght="50" /></a>
       <a href="#" onclick="changeImage(4);"><img src="images/4.jpg" width="50" hieght="50" /></a>
       <a href="#" onclick="changeImage(5);"><img src="images/5.jpg" width="50" hieght="50" /></a>
       <a href="#" onclick="changeImage(6);"><img src="images/6.jpg" width="50" hieght="50" /></a> <br/>
       <a href="#" onclick="changeImage();">Clear Back Ground Image </a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Changebg.js**

```
 function changeImage(number)
 {
 $.Post('core/changebg.php',{number:number},
     function(data)
     {
      $('body').css('background-image','url("images/'+number+'.jpg")');

     });

}

function clearImage() {

  $.Get('core/changebg.php?resetBg',
    function(data) {
      $('body').css('background-image'.'');
    });


}
```

Changebg.php

```
        <?php
      if(isset($_Post['number'])) {
        SESSION_START();
        $_SESSION['image'] = $_Post['number'];

      }

       if(isset($_Get['resetBg'])) {

         SESSION_START();
         SESSION_destroy();

       }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using two methods of `jQuery` that do not exist.

Replace `$.Post` and `$.Get` in your code with `$.post` `$.get`

Docs here [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

You have same errors in your PHP code.

To access post and get params you must use `$_POST` and `$_GET`.